# Checking two arrays for matches

Tags: javascript, array

Is there a better way to do this?

```
    var duplicate = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < acceptedFiles.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < attachments.attachments.length; j++) {
            if (attachments.attachments[j].name === acceptedFiles[i].name) {
                duplicate = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should keep a look out for [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) this would allow you to build a `set` of your `acceptedFiles` and pass that around. Thus you could remove the outer `for` loop and simply query the set if the attachment is accepted. If you have many accepted types, this could also speed up significantly as you go from \$\mathcal{O}(nk)\$ to \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$.

Answer (score 8):

Presumably, once a `duplicate` is found you don't need to continue looping:

```
if (attachments.attachments[j].name === acceptedFiles[i].name) {
    duplicate = true;
}
```

With JavaScript, the best thing would be to wrap up your `for` loops in a function:

```
function containsDuplicate(acceptedFiles, attachments) {
    for (var i = 0; i < acceptedFiles.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < attachments.attachments.length; j++) {
            if (attachments.attachments[j].name === acceptedFiles[i].name) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

As this is a problem that applies to multiple languages, look at the `break` keyword.

Comment: @anorton I can't quite wrap my head around how that works here. When `i = 1` we are missing the comparison of `x[1]` to `y[0]`?

Comment: Oops.  I read `attachments` and `acceptedFiles` as the same array. If we were looking for duplicates in the same array, it works.  sorry.

Comment: @anorton Ahhhhhh that makes sense now

Answer (score 2):

If using external libraries is an option, then LoDash would allow for something more like:

```
var duplicate = _.intersection(_.pluck(acceptedFiles, 'name'),
    _.pluck(attachments, 'name')).length > 0;
```

or:

```
function areDuplicates(acceptedFiles, attachments) {
    var acceptedFileNames = _.pluck(acceptedFiles, 'name');
    var attachmentNames = _.pluck(attachments, 'name');
    return _.intersection(acceptedFileNames, attachmentNames).length > 0;
}
```

Comment: I like this (and it's more concise so +1), but in terms of performance, it's probably less efficient than the OP's existing code

Answer (score 2):

Using ES5 you can generally avoid having to do tedious for loops to iterate through the values.  In this case you can use the [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method on arrays in order avoid using a flag and having `i` and `j` iterators to get the array values.  You also get the added bonus of `some` short circuiting and stopping when the first true is found so as far as big O notation it is more efficient.

```
function hasDuplicate() {
    return acceptedFiles.some(function(acceptedValue) {
        return attachments.attachments.some(function(attachmentValue) {
            return acceptedValue.name === attachmentValue.name;
        });
    });
}
```

If your browser doesn't support ES5 you can use a [shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim)

Answer (score 1):

You can return as soon as a match is found.

```
for (var i = 0; i < acceptedFiles.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < attachments.attachments.length; j++) {
        if (attachments.attachments[j].name === acceptedFiles[i].name) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```